# Calcium Nitrate - Why only 18.8% Calcium for fertiliser?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I brought a kilo of Calcium Nitrate for my hydroponic setup.

The chemical formula for Calium Nitrate is Ca(NO3)2. I did a quick calculation of its weight:

Ca = 1*40.078

N  = 2*14.006 = 28.012

O  = 6*15.999 = 95.999

---

Total = 164.085

Hence the % in weight of calcium is ~24.42%.

BUT I see on the fertilizer pack that Calcium is only 18.8% and Nitrogen is 15.5%

Eg: https://www.fertinagroindia.com/calcium-nitrate.html

Why is this?

Comment: Your math seems fine. The manufacturer, on the other hand, doesn't know how to market the stuff properly. The URL suggests "*The content of Ca in our fertilizer is 24% that exceed our foreign analogues on 5%, their calcium nitrate contains only 19% of Ca.*", whereas label on the package says "Ca–18.80%". If it's really  98% Ca(No3)2 as they claim, then it's about 24% Ca, as you suggested.

Comment: Also note that the element content in fertilizers is sometimes given for the corresponding *oxide* – this is a common practice for potassium (K2O).

Comment: I understand your point. But even other suppliers,  I think this is generally the case. ex: https://www.amazon.com/Calcium-Nitrate-15-5-0-0-Fertilizer-POUNDS/dp/B071YS779G

Comment: That's due to impurities. They list a bunch of extra stuff even on the label (chlorine, ammonia salts etc.) and it's easier to claim slightly lower content of the main product to avoid a lawsuit if the product doesn't meet the standards (for instance, gets moisturized due to improper storing conditions). If you really want to know the exact content, don't rely on what manufacturer tells you and do quantitative analysis for calcium yourself.

Comment: Also note the the calcium nitrate is hygroscopic and is usually provided as tetrahydrate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_nitrate

Comment: Oh Yes, I see now. @Poutnik. Wiki says: The fertilizer grade (15.5-0-0 + 19% Ca) is popular in the greenhouse and hydroponics trades; it contains ammonium nitrate and water, as the "double salt" {\displaystyle {\ce {5Ca(NO3)2.NH4NO3.10H2O}}} {\displaystyle {\ce {5Ca(NO3)2.NH4NO3.10H2O}}}.

Comment: @Nujufas Well, I guess now you can answer your own question:)

Comment: @Nujufas You are welcome. I have noticed the double salt as well, but was not sure if it was your case.